# How could i stop elastic after i run it via gradle?

Tags: elasticsearch, gradle

Here is my code where i start

```
task runElastic(type:Exec, dependsOn: ['taskUnzip']) {
    workingDir "${buildDir}/unpacked/dist/elasticsearch-7.6.0/bin"

    if (System.getProperty('os.name').toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).contains('windows')) {
        commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'elasticsearch.bat'
    } else {
        commandLine './elasticsearch'
    }
}
```

May be i could fetch pid of the process and kill by them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution,
I stop elastic by port

```
if (OS.contains("windows")) {
    killByPort = "cmd /c \"for /f \"tokens=5\" %a in ('netstat -aon ^| find \":9200\" ^| find " +
            "\"LISTENING\"') do " +
            "taskkill /f /pid %a\"";
} else  {
    killByPort = "sh -c PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin && kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:9200)";
}
```